# Primeiro item de um ArrayList duplicado

Tags: android, android-fragment

Olá, tenho o código abaixo que parece estar funcionando corretamente, o problema é que o primeiro item da lista ou fica em branco ou copia os dados do último item da lista.

```
public class TabList extends ListFragment {

    JSONObject jsonObj;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    TabListAdapter adapter;
    Timer myTimer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();
        if (myTimer != null) myTimer.cancel();
        createTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause () {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    private void createTimer () {
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateList();
            }
        }, 0, 10000);
    }

    public void updateList () {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String, String> nearby = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
                if (nearby.get("nearby") != null) {
                    try {
                        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(nearby.get("nearby"));
                        jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                            User userNearby;
                            userNearby = new User();
                            userNearby.setFirstname(jsonObj.getString("firstname"));
                            userNearby.setLastname(jsonObj.getString("lastname"));
                            userNearby.setPlate(jsonObj.getString("plate"));
                            userNearby.setEmail(jsonObj.getString("email"));
                            userNearby.setLat(jsonObj.getDouble("lat"));
                            userNearby.setLng(jsonObj.getDouble("lng"));
                            userNearby.setStatus(jsonObj.getString("status"));
                            userNearby.setDistance(jsonObj.getDouble("distance"));
                            userList.add(userNearby);
                        }
                        adapter = new TabListAdapter(getActivity(), userList);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Não sei se estou esquecendo de algo pois estou aplicando o dapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); e também não vejo necessidade de usar um userlist.clear(), correto?

O código do TabListAdapter:

```
package br.com.nerd.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import br.com.nerd.autodate.R;
import br.com.nerd.autodate.model.User;

public class TabListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<User> userItems;

    public TabListAdapter (Activity activity, List<User> userItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.userItems = userItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return userItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        ImageView picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView plate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plate);
        TextView distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);

        if (position > 0) {
            User m = userItems.get(position);
            plate.setText(m.getPlate() + " (" + m.getStatus() + ")");
            name.setText(m.getFirstname() + " " + m.getLastname());
            distance.setText(m.getDistance().toString());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: dbam, não vejo nada de errado nesse código, a chamada ao `notifyDataSetChanged` esta correta... Poderia colocar o código do `TabListAdapter`? Poderia também debugar e verificar se o `jsonArray` esta com os itens corretamente?

Comment: Olá @Wakin, obrigado novamente. Incluí o código do TabListAdapter. Quanto ao jsonArray, já havia debugado e está correto.

Answer (score 1):

Troquei:

```
    if (position > 0) {
        User m = userItems.get(position);
        plate.setText(m.getPlate() + " (" + m.getStatus() + ")");
        name.setText(m.getFirstname() + " " + m.getLastname());
        distance.setText(m.getDistance().toString());
    }
```

por isso:

```
        User m = userItems.get(position);
        plate.setText(m.getPlate() + " (" + m.getStatus() + ")");
        name.setText(m.getFirstname() + " " + m.getLastname());
        distance.setText(m.getDistance().toString());
```

Agora não me perguntem por que havia colocado isso antes.